# Error using Ember/Handlebars with BPM

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to get Ember running with BPM based on these instructions:

https://github.com/bpm/bpm/wiki/Using-BPM-with-SproutCore-2.0

Everything seems to work fine until I try to add an expression to the Handlebars template:

```
Congratulations!  You are running HelloWorld v{{MyApp.VERSION}}
```

Then I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'a.charAt(0)')
```

If I remove the expression, everything works fine.

The source is here: https://github.com/nicholasjhenry/bpm_ember

Can anyone provide determine why this error is occurring?

Edit: The line that is throwing the error is:

```
function normalizePath(path) {
  ember_assert('must pass non-empty string to normalizePath()', path && path!=='');

  if (path==='*') return path; //special case...

  var first = path.charAt(0); // <======
```

which is called by Ember.watch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT (2012/01/03)**

I have updated the packages on GetBPM.org so now they work out of the box. All you have to do is run `bpm add ember` in your project directory and everything will work fine. I also have updated using BPM with Ember.js instructions here: https://github.com/ud3323/bpm/wiki/Using-BPM-with-Ember.

Comment: The easier way is to clone ember from github and use it in the vendor directory. On vendoring packages see the bpm wiki entry https://github.com/bpm/bpm/wiki/Vendoring-Projects-and-Packages. That way it's easy to always use one of the newest ember builds.